# android...CoordinatorLayout Rendering issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

After I updated Android Studio to v3.1.3 I am having this rendering issue!

build.grandle (app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, it was resolved by changing this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

It helped me resolve my rendering problems

Comment: Make sure you let your project sync after changing this line of code

Comment: If a problem still persists change constraint layout from 1.1.2 to 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have in your build.gradle

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

if you do not need to restart the android studio cache

in the menu file> invalidate caches / restart

Comment: I added my build.gradle dependencies in the post. I do have the implementation in my build.gradle. But it does not work. And i also have reinstalled android studio but still does not work.

Comment: try menu (build > clean project) wait for the job to finish and then (build > rebuild project)

Comment: Sure! I added a screenshot of my SDK Tools.